# Wordpress Pagination for a custom page template and custom post type

Tags: pagination

Edited: Answered below.

I'm using the following query to paginate my posts on a Custom Page template that pulls a Custom Post type. this exact code works on Author.php, but this custom template Page, "Filmmaking" does not show the pagination. I have a simple, tried and true pagination function after my loop. Why would it work for author.php, but not for page-filmmaking.php?

```
<?php

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$film_query = array( 
'post_type' => 'filmmaking',   // Custom Post Type
'paged' => $paged,       // Set it up to be paged so you can use pagination
'posts_per_page' => 2,   // How many to show per page
);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $film_query );

?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
```

**Answer: Get rid of if has_posts. 
Working Code:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: pagination test
 */

get_header(); ?>
<?php //get_sidebar(); ?>
<div id="page-left">
<?php
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query(array(
'post_type'=>'filmmaking',
'paged' => $paged,
'posts_per_page' => 2,
));

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

<?php  endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Nyare') ?>
<?php next_posts_link(' Äldre &raquo;') ?>

</div><!-- page left -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```